# время жизни ViewScoped бина

Tags: java, jsf

Использую JSF с CDI ViewScoped бином. Насколько я понял, ViewScoped должен жить, пока в браузере открыта вкладка с ним. Однако, через длительное время бин исчезает. Минут 10-20 и возможно даже 30 он живет, а через час его нет. Никаких сессионных бинов у меня нет. Во время тестов со страницей никто не работает.

Можете просветить как долго живет ViewScoped на самом деле и что можно сделать что бы он жил ровно столько, сколько живет вкладка с ним.

Comment: Вот ответ на Ваш вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391453/1341148, а конкретно - последний пункт в перечислении возможных причин

Comment: т.е. все же сессия. Спасибо.